# problem redirecting users to page on login

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I'm trying to redirect certain users to a part of my site but I cannot seem to make it work... can you take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'redirect_after_login' ) ) :
    function redirect_after_login() {
        global $user_ID;
        if ( $user_ID === 4 ) {
            global $redirect_to;
            if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
                $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl') . '/stock-de-sexitive/';
            }
   }
}
endif;
add_action('auth_redirect', 'redirect_after_login');
```

Also, I know globals are dangerous, so if you know of a canonical approach that would be great too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect). And don't forget to exit.

Comment: Yeah, I did something like that and it worked, may I ask you about the exit? what did you mean by that?

Comment: Add `exit;` after the redirect. Else you'll end in an endless loop.